# Unable to provision cluster in databricks using GCP

Tags: databricks

I am trying to create databricks cluster on GCP but getting error like

> No active Google Kubernetes Engine cluster found for workspace.

Retrying Google Kubernetes Engine cluster creation. All required APIs are enabled still same issue, can someone please help here. Thanks

Comment: have you increased quotas? https://docs.gcp.databricks.com/getting-started/try-databricks-gcp.html

Comment: Thanks Alex, i tried with default, but dont have privilege to update quotas..